# What is the source for historical stock chart prices?

Tags: charts, finance, yahoo-finance, stockquotes, google-finance

Yahoo does not seem to be using historical close prices nor are they using historical Adjusted close prices for their charts. For example, if you look at PCG on July 3, 1980, the data looks like this (close of 5.34):

Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close

1980-07-03,5.34,5.34,5.31,5.34,99200,0.04

However, on the interactive chart, Yahoo shows this price on July 3, 1980: 
2.6695

On Google's chart, it shows 12.188 for that date. It is also missing some dates.

What is going on? I am beginning to doubt the integrity of stock charts.

Does anyone know what source data Yahoo (or Google) uses for their stock charts?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://eoddata.com, very good source of data.